# Select muliple files does not function

Tags: software-installation, system, fonts

I recently downloaded and installed elementary OS 5.1.6 Hera and am very happy with it except for some issues I am having with the shift+ select multiple files in various areas when it comes to downloading certain things like fonts. It highlights but does not connect in Font Manager I just installed. Only one font gets installed.

Thank you

Comment: Because it is Linux, not Windows or any OS from Apple. If you want to install fonts in Linux all you have to do is to find out where fonts are stored in Linux and copy all fonts to proper location at once. There is no need to install them one by one. That is how I always do in Linux. Actually I behave the way by thinking how I can achieve it through terminal. The GUI in Linux os like a kind of layout on the top of terminal. If you will bear in mind this fact, then you will focus how to use terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is mentioned by @Sysadmin. I adding further detail for ease understanding.
The fonts are stored in `/usr/share/fonts` folder. Just open this folder as administrator and copy-paste all eh fonts you downloaded in respective folders such as `OpenType`, `TrueType` and extract the files if it is in zip.

After this, the fonts will be available in all Softwares across your system. In case if your software is open while doing this process. You have to close and reopen for the font to be available.